# Verify COM+ package status with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, com+

I've scripted the start and stop of COM+ applications on a remote server using PowerShell:

```
function Set-ComPlusStatus {
    $comPlusApps=Get-Content $comPlusAppList
    $comObj=New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
    $comObj.Connect($server)
    ForEach($comPlusApp in $comPlusApps) {
        if($setStatus="stop") {
            $comObj.ShutdownApplication($comPlusApp)
        }
        elseif($setStatus="start") {
            $comObj.StartApplication($comPlusApp)
        }
    }
}
```

This function works i.e. it stops/starts the COM+ packages listed in the reference txt document ($comPlusAppList) as expected.

However, I would like to add some form of verification/validation to confirm that the function has been successful; ideally I'd like to check the status of the specific packages and write a success/fail message back to host based on the status.

How can the COM+ package status (stopped/running) be accessed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Following script works:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $compname -ScriptBlock{ $Catalog = New-   Object -com COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog 
$oapplications = $catalog.getcollection("Applications") 
$oapplications.populate()
foreach ($oapplication in $oapplications){ 
$skeyappli = $oapplication.key 
$oappliInstances = $oapplications.getcollection("ApplicationInstances",$skeyappli) 
$oappliInstances.populate() 
# To verify if application is started 
If ($oappliInstances.count -eq 0) { 
    Write-Host "Application"$oapplication.value("Name")"is stopped" -ForegroundColor Red 
    } Else{ 
        Write-Host "Application"$oapplication.value("Name")"is Running" -ForegroundColor Green 
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide a hint of answer. I've been trying to figure this out but haven't yet. This link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684369(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should provide what you need, although I haven't figured out how to enumerate the PropertyInfo collection for the applications.